# Why object literal can access the property of Object's prototype?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

While reading Processional JavaScript for Web Developers 4th edition, I found the saying:

> When defining an object via object literal notation, the Object constructor is never actually called.

But if the object literal isn't created through `Object` constructor, how can it access the property of `Object.prototype`?

Like this:

```js
Object.prototype.a = 1
let obj = {}
console.log(obj.a)      // 1
```

Or can anyone tell me how the conclusion given by the book come out? I didn't find anything about this in ECMAScript specification.

Comment: It doesn't have to call the constructor to get assigned the prototype.

Comment: `{}` doesn't explicitly call *any* constructor, yet it's an instance of something. That happens implicitly behind the scenes.

Comment: @CherryDT You mean it has its own way to connect with the `Object.prototype`?

Comment: You can do that too, you can set something's prototype using `Object.setPrototypeOf`.

Comment: @CherryDT Yes, I know I can do that. But has the ECMAScript specification said anything about that? Where can I find it ?

Comment: [It](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-object-initializer-runtime-semantics-evaluation) calls [OrdinaryObjectCreate](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ordinary-and-exotic-objects-behaviours.html#sec-ordinaryobjectcreate) (like `Object.create()` btw), which doesn't call the Object constructor.

Comment: "*the Object constructor is never actually called*" is a bold statement to make. We don't actually know, since it is impossible to observe what happens in the engine - all we can tell is that the result is actually the same.

Comment: @Bergi we can observe that `window.Object` is not called, we can also read from the specs that the [Object constructor](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-object-constructor) is not called in this case. So yes, an implementation could probably call the original Object constructor and still have a behavior that conforms with the specs, but I doubt any implementation does.

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, I meant it might call `realm.%Object`, not `global.Object` which you could mutate

Comment: @Kaiido `OrdinaryObjectCreate` is to do with `object literal` while `OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor` is to do with `Object constructor`, right?

Comment: @Chor Don't misread the standard. This is how the behavior is specified, not how any calls are necessarily implemented.

Answer (score 0):

To [quote MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

> Objects are created *as if* a call to new Object() were made; that is,
> objects made from object literal expressions *are instances of Object*.

So, in your code `obj` 'automagically' becomes instance of `Object`.

The assignment of `Object.prototype.a` in your code will create `a` as property of everything that inherits from `Object` (in js that is: ***everything***) you create subsequently.

```js
Object.prototype.a = 'I am the one';
let obj = {};
let Constrctr = function(aa = this.a) {
  //                          ^ QED
  this.aa = aa;
  
};
let obj2 = new Constrctr();
let obj3 = new Constrctr(2);
let someArray = new Array();
let someArrayLiteral = [];
let someNumber = new Number();
let someNumberLiteral = 42;
let someRegex = new RegExp();
let someString = new String();
let someStringLiteral = "";
let someFunction = () => {};

document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = `<h2><i>Everything</i></h2>obj.a: ${obj.a},
obj2.aa: ${obj2.aa}, 
obj2.a: ${obj2.a},
obj3.aa: ${obj3.aa},
obj3.a: ${obj3.a},
someNumber.a: ${someNumber.a},
someNumberLiteral.a: ${someNumberLiteral.a},
someArray.a: ${someArray.a},
someArrayLiteral.a: ${someArray.a},
someRegex.a: ${someRegex.a},
someString.a: ${someString.a},
someStringLiteral.a: ${someStringLiteral.a},
someFunction.a: ${someFunction.a}`;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```